# Nodejs web hosting

Tags: javascript, node.js, webserver, port

Im making a election software using nodejs, js and html. Creently im using port 3000 to host the static files in public file and listen in port 4000 for request from the frontend to edit the database. I need a way to do both using a single port.

Explaining more: I have a public file with html and js code and also a poll.json file that stores all data. So using port 3000 im hosting this public file. In the frontend i use a port request to port 4000 sending the voting details to edit in the database. Im new to HOSTING server and confused by various methods to do it.

This is my code for now:

```
const createServer = require('http').createServer;
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
let pollData = require(__dirname+'/public/poll.json');
var fs = require('fs');
var all_usn_no=[];
const listening_port=4000;
//const hosting_port=process.env.PORT || 3000;
const hosting_port=3000;

function get_roll_and_usn(pollData){
  for(var i=0;i<=pollData.students.length-1;i++){
      //all_roll_no.push(pollData.students[i][0]);
      all_usn_no.push(pollData.students[i][1]);
  }
}
function roll_to_row(in_usn){
  get_roll_and_usn(pollData)
  return all_usn_no.indexOf(in_usn);
}
function write_vote(votes){
  var checking_row=roll_to_row(votes[1]);
  pollData.students[checking_row]=votes;
  fs.writeFile(__dirname+'/public/poll.json', JSON.stringify(pollData), (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('Data written to file');
  });
}


const server_listen = createServer((req, res) => {
  let body = '';
  req.on('data', data => body += data)
  req.on('end', () => {
    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET',
    });
    body=body.split(",");
    console.log(body.toString());
    write_vote(body);

    res.end(`{ "response": "${body ? body : 'No body sent' }" }`);
  })
});
server_listen.listen(listening_port, () => {
  console.log('Server listening on '+listening_port);
} );



var server_host = app.listen(hosting_port, 'localhost',function(){
  console.log('listening for requests on port '+hosting_port);
});
//Static files
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

EDIT: currently i have edited my code like this.

```
const createServer = require('http').createServer;
var express = require('express');

var finalhandler = require('finalhandler');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
var serve = serveStatic('/public');

let pollData = require(__dirname+'/public/poll.json');
var fs = require('fs');
var all_usn_no=[];
const listening_port=3000;

function get_roll_and_usn(pollData){
  for(var i=0;i<=pollData.students.length-1;i++){
      //all_roll_no.push(pollData.students[i][0]);
      all_usn_no.push(pollData.students[i][1]);
  }
}
function roll_to_row(in_usn){
  get_roll_and_usn(pollData)
  return all_usn_no.indexOf(in_usn);
}
function write_vote(votes){
  var checking_row=roll_to_row(votes[1]);
  pollData.students[checking_row]=votes;
  fs.writeFile(__dirname+'/public/poll.json', JSON.stringify(pollData), (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('Data written to file');
  });
}

const server_listen = createServer((req, res) => {
  if (req.method === "GET") {
    fs.createReadStream("./public/index.html", "UTF-8").pipe(res);
  }
  else if (req.method === "POST") {
    console.log('post request');
    let body = '';
    req.on('data', data => body += data)
    req.on('end', () => {
      res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET',
      });
      body=body.split(",");
      console.log(body.toString());
      write_vote(body);

      res.end(`{ "response": "${body ? body : 'No body sent' }" }`);
    })
  }
});

server_listen.listen(listening_port, () => {
  console.log('Server listening on '+listening_port);
});
```

But still im able to only host the index.html. But i want to host the whole pubic file. I tried somoe solution from internet that only brings errors. How can i host the public file now ?

Comment: Why aren't you simply using same port with different url for static files and request, or in more general with different type of requests(get or post)? Please explain the question more

Comment: I don't get/understand how to use different url. This code itself i just coped from internet which works. Now modifying it seems confusing. Would be helpful if you could show what i should change.

Comment: There are many ways of doing this. All require learning more about express methods first. An extremely simple way would be to serve static files for `GET` requests to the server and record votes when the front end sends a `POST` request. The `app.get` and `app.post` methods you would use are covered in [Express documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to import http module as express will be enough. What you need is to use only one port number for express. You are creating two different servers. Express will be enough to create a server.

> NOTE1- by setting `app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'))` you are telling express to add all files inside public to url. E.g. `image.png` in public folder can be accessed at `localhost:3000/image.png` url

> NOTE2- the below code will maybe not satisfy your need as it is not clear that what is inside body variable.

You must read at least 5 chapters from [here](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html). There are next button below the page to go to next chapter.

Further reading [this](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_http.asp) before anything else will more clearly clarify things.read 5 chapters

Your code should be like-

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
let pollData = require(__dirname+'/public/poll.json');
var fs = require('fs');
var all_usn_no=[];

//Static files
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));

//below will be your homepage(I.e. "localhost:3000/ ")
  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

  app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    let body=JSON.parse(req.body);
        console.log(body.toString());
        write_vote(body);

});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
});

function get_roll_and_usn(pollData){
  for(var i=0;i<=pollData.students.length-1;i++){
      //all_roll_no.push(pollData.students[i][0]);
      all_usn_no.push(pollData.students[i][1]);
  }
}
function roll_to_row(in_usn){
  get_roll_and_usn(pollData)
  return all_usn_no.indexOf(in_usn);
}
function write_vote(votes){
  var checking_row=roll_to_row(votes[1]);
  pollData.students[checking_row]=votes;
  fs.writeFile(__dirname+'/public/poll.json', JSON.stringify(pollData), (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('Data written to file');
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks this actually worked. I only had to replace the code i had in my post request and then it worked Just as needed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Pranav Kumar you should, even then, read the docs in the links given. It will make you better